# How to change the value of a global variable in a function while there is a local variable of same name in C#

Tags: variables, c#-4.0, global-variables, local

I want to change the global variable in a function where a local variable of same is already present.

```
int x=10;     //global variable
void fun1()
{
fun2(5);
}

void fun2(int x)
{
x=7;       //here i want that this statement assigns the value 7 to the global x
}
```

Comment: By "global variable" you really mean "instance variable" - it's not global, as it's specific to an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the local parameter value.
Like Yuriy Vikulov said.
`this.x` for non-static variables

```
int x=10;     //global variable
void fun1()
{
fun2(5);
}

void fun2(int lx)
{
x=7;  //if you want 7
x=lx;  //if you want the paramValue
}
```

Comment: is there any other way without changing the name og the parameter value?

Comment: Yes. use 'this.x' for globalvariable and 'x' for the local

Answer (score 1):

Just qualify it with `this`. It's a pretty common pattern, particularly for constructors:

```
public class Player
{
    private readonly string name;

    public Player(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

While I view it as acceptable if your parameter really is meant to be a new value for the field (potentially in a method which creates a new instance based on the current one and the new value for the single field, for example), I would *try* to avoid it in general, just from a readability perspective. Of course, the names of your private fields are an implementation detail, but when reading the code for the method, it's confusing to have two *different* concepts represented by the same variable name.

Answer (score 0):

`this.x` for non-static classes

`NameClass.x` for static variables